# how to call a variable from a function

Tags: function, powershell, variables

```
function test{
  for($a=0;$a -le 2;$a++){
     if($a -eq 1){break}
  }
}
#----outside----
write-output $a
```

How to call a variable from a function and not to use `return` to get `$a` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from using [scopes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes) as described in [Rob's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60090371/9898643), there is also the possibility to send a parameter by [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_ref).

This means that inside the function, a reference to the original variable is used, so whatever the function does with it, the original value is affected.

The downside is that when using references, you must use the `Value` property of the System.Management.Automation.PSReference type to access/alter your data as in the example below:

```
function test ([ref]$a) {
  for ($a.Value = 0; $a.Value -le 2; $a.Value++){
     if ($a.Value -eq 1) {break}
  }
}

#----outside----
$a = 0 
test ([ref]$a)  # the parameter needs to be wrapped inside brackets and prefixed by [ref]
Write-Output $a
```

When sending a parameter that is an object type, like for instance a Hashtable, then by default it is always passed to the function by reference and for those you don't use the `[ref]` accellerator.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to set the variable global?

```
$var="Test"
function test()
{
    $global:var="blub"
}
test
$var
```

or

```
$a = 0

function test{
  for($global:a=0;$global:a -le 2;$global:a++){
     if($global:a -eq 1){break}
  }
}
test
write-output $a
```

Comment: The [script scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-7#scope-modifiers) will be enough I gather.